# How to conditionally load CSS and JS files in the HEAD for Wordpress plugins

Tags: plugins, wordpress

Some wordpress plugins like image galleries require specific CSS or Javascript files to load in the HEAD. But let's say you do not want to load these files on all other pages of your wordpress site, because that gallery is on a secondary page which your website visitors don't access very often.

I normally use `wp_enqueue_style`/`wp_enqueue_script` on `wp_print_styles`/`wp_print_scripts` action hooks, outside the php plugin function. If I put `wp_enqueue_style' inside the plugin function, then the CSS/JS will load only when the plugin is displayed, but it won't load in the HEAD, which is what I need.

So what do you do when you want these files to be loaded in the HEAD only when the plugin function is echoed? Either as a shortcode, widget or direct call of the php plugin function.

Comment: in what action do you add your styles and scripts?

Comment: on wp_print_styles / wp_print_scripts, but I'd like to do it only on the pages that call the plugin function (either directly, through shortcode or widget)